# Meteor Velocity starting Mirror is slow

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

I'm trying to create some unit test with Mocha and Velocity. 
however when i go to my webpage and click the velocity bullet, I get the message "mocha - mirror starting".

It is stuck there for around 10min, however CPU is hitting 100% so it is doing something, when i look in the logs i don't find anything. When i browse to the location where Velocity is started, I get an empty response. After that it bubbles up, but this is not acceptable. Unit test are supposed to be fast...

> I20151223-11:**43**:59.571(1)? [velocity] *** Meteor Tools is installing ***
>
> I20151223-11:43:59.572(1)? This takes a few minutes the first time.
>
> I20151223-11:43:59.572(1)? [velocity] You can see the mirror logs at: tail -f D:\Work\coderepository\meteor\sandwich-app.meteor\local\log\mocha.log
>
> I20151223-11:**52**:36.853(1)? mocha: 2 tests passed (11ms)

Any help? I'm running on a Windows 10 machine. 
I'm new to Meteor and Velocity so I could be doing something wrong. I only have the sample-tests added...

I tried to run meteor in debug mode, but this doesn't add any more information into the mocha.log file

Rob

Comment: It says it takes a few minutes the first time... So does it happen every time?

Comment: yes, every time. If it would be the first time, no hard feelings but every time is to much. only when the applications stays alive it is ok.

Comment: Mine took 30 minutes for the first time. but, after that the tests ran under 2 minutes. In Mac, it is quite fast. 2 minutes for the first time, and instantaneous after that.